# What am I doing wrong with accessing this array element?

Tags: 7, forms

```
  $form['cookie']['saved'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'How long?',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

But if I do:

```
  if ($form_state['values']['cookie']['saved'] == 'Dog the Bounty Hunter') {
    form_set_error('dog_error', t("That doesn't make any sense."));
  }
```

I get an error that the 'cookie' index doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you make sure $form['cookie'] will saving to $form_state['values'] ?

Answer (score 3):

Install the [development module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and do `dpm($form, 'the form');` and `dpm($form_state, 'my form state');` in your form alter function. I believe you'll see that `$form_state` is "flattened" to only the innermost values of your form array.

So, the `saved` array key exists, not `[cookie][saved]`.

*In general try to make use of this convention, or assumption by drupal.* Usually your FAPI form has fieldset(s) as outer keys (not passed into $form_state at all, they only affect the appearence of the form) and input values as inner keys. So rename your 2nd key from `saved` to `cookie_saved`.

If you really (for some reason) want the `['cookie']['saved']` to be in `$form_state` just as-is -- perserving the hierarchy of information. You would want to set the `#tree` property of `cookie` in your FAPI array.

See these 2 resources of information:

- [Legacy drupal page talking about FAPI usage](http://drupal.org/node/48643)
- [current FAPI quickstart guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

Both are relevant for background information how FAPI usage and how its evolved to meet our needs as developers. Search for `#tree` and `#parents` within the linked documentation pages.

Answer (score 0):

Array 'cookie' using only to group form items but to get value you need to use 'saved' key:

```
if ($form_state['values']['saved'] == 'Dog the Bounty Hunter') {
  form_set_error('dog_error', t("That doesn't make any sense."));
}
```